# Iterating through a map with multiple items

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an item map that looks like this:

```
final Map<String, List> _items = <String, List>{
    'Tea' : ['2','Hot', 'Large'],
    'Orange Juice' : ['1','Cold', 'Large'],
// and so on....
}
```

I need to map through to display all four parameters inside `CarouselSlider` slider. using a variable for each element for each iteration.

something like this would work if _items was a normal list like this: ['element1', 'element2']
( you need to add carousel_slider: ^2.2.1, the result will be pages that can be slided horizontally)

```
MaterialApp(
      home: CarouselSlider(
        options: CarouselOptions(height: 400.0),
        items: _items.map((i) {
          return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Text(i);
          });
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Do you want all the elements present in different lists in a single list and provide that to items ?

Comment: I'm creating a general view with variables that should be replaced by the elements ```['2','Hot', 'Large'],``` in every iteration to create a slidable shop items for example. For example it would have a Text widget that should take the price argument.. something like this: ```Text('${.....}')``` and another field for size so it is replaced with $2 for Tea and then $1 for Orange Juice for every iteration... creating 2 slides in ```CarouselSlider```.